# Can't access environment variable from Rails 3.1 initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, environment-variables, ruby-on-rails-3.1, omniauth

I have an initializer file that looks like this:

```
  Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do  
    provider :facebook, '000000000000000', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  end
```

And my app works.

I don't want to hardcode credentials so I changed it to:

```
  Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do  
    provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET']
  end
```

I set the corresponding environment variables in bash, and restarted my app.

When I use the rails console, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'] and  ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'] output the correct values.

But my app does not work anymore, I get a response with  "Missing client_id parameter" when using omniauth.

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Missing client_id parameter.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

I'm confused.

Isn't it the correct way to access environment variables ? Does it work another way in initializers ?

How can I access the environment variables from the initializer ?

BTW I'm using Ubuntu 11.04.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something about being inside the block overrides ENV and env.  This is the omniauth suggested way:

https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Dynamic-Providers